# I need to access the value within a const std::string& call in a function

Tags: c++

I have a quick question regarding C++ and references to values. I have been asked to write a function that takes the input from const std::string& and use the input to perform some tasks. The issue is, I have no idea how to access the value. I know it is a pass-by reference value but I don't know how to access it within the function.
This is the code that I was given:

```
    #include "rle.hpp"

std::string func_send(const std::string&)
{
    //Implement !

   
    return {};
}


std::string func_receive(const std::string&)
{
    // Implement!

    return {};
}
```

Comment: `std::string str = std::string&;` is not valid, so I doubt that's the code that you were given

Comment: `(const std::string&)` it's not possible to access that value, so I double that's the code that you were given either.

Comment: This is the code I was given:

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing a function prototype and a function prototype? If that really is what you were given, fix it by naming the parameter `(const std::string& value)` and complain.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am. I have contacted the person who assigned this to me to figure out if I am allowed to change it to figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

The code you were given makes no sense, at least there is no way to acces the parameter because it has no name. Moreover `std::string str = std::string&;` is invalid syntax, I don't know what it is supposed to mean. Give the parameter a name:

```
std::string func_send(const std::string& str)
                                     //   ^------------ !!!
{
    std::string some_other_string = str; 
    return {};   // missing semi-colon
}
```

Comment: `std::string some_other_string = str;` is probably not needed.